# Limit posts per author/role

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a function that will kill Wordpress if the person tries to post more than five posts and is also in the specific role (s2member 1). I am using a custom post type.

```
global $current_user; // get the current author
$userid = $current_user->ID;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'author' => $userid
);
$the_posts = get_posts ( $args ); // get the published posts for that author
$post_count = count($the_posts); // count the number of published posts for the author
$N = 5; // set number for max posts per user
if ($post_count > $N) {
    if (current_user_is('s2member_level1')) {   
        wp_die( 'message' ); // if the number of posts is more than N, kill the current post attempt so the author can't post
    }
}
```

Comment: The code as is should work. What's not working for you?

Comment: Why aren't you checking `current_user_is('s2member_level1')` before running the query?

Comment: @JosephSilber I changed the above code to reflect the greater than. I am new to programming in php. Can I use this operator, or do I need to express greater than in another way? If so, how?

Comment: When I moved  current_user_is('s2member_level1') outside the query, it does not cause WordPress to die, no matter how many posts the user has. It just isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple:

```
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $user_ID ); // get total post for user
if ($user_post_count > 1) { // define number 

<your code here> // code here

}
```